# First derivative of a quadratic function

Tags: derivatives

I have the following question about the derivative.

> Find out the quadratic function, which takes the value $41$ at $x=-2$ and the value $20$ at $x=5$ and is minimized at $x=2$ . Calculate the minimum value of this function.

If the function is minimized at $x=2$, then $f'(2) = 0$.

My question is: the derivative of the quadratic is a line tangent to the function or the slope of the function for a given $x$? Then the derivative equals $0$ because it is minimized at the vertex and at the vertex there is no slope?

This is not really about the question above but i just want to be sure if that is the case.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "linear function derived from the quadratic", do you mean the linear function that is tangent to the quadratic at that point?

Comment: Yes I just didn’t really know how to put it, I’m not sure if iam clear sorry

Comment: Okay. Yes, a line tangent to $f$ at $x=2$ has slope $0$.

Comment: I mean the line tangent to the function, sorry for the confusion

Comment: It equals 0 because there is no slope in the vertex?

Comment: Typically when slope is zero we don't say there is "no slope" but that the slope exists and is zero.

Comment: Ok I get it, thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

**Given**

- $f(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + C.$
- $f(-2) = 41.$
- $f(5) = 20.$
- $f(x)$ achieves a minimum at $x = 2.$

**To do:**

- Determine $A,B,C.$
- Determine $f(2).$

---

$f'(x) = 2Ax + B$ and $f''(x) = 2A.$

From the constraint that $f(x)$ has a minimum at $x=2,$ you conclude that $f'(2) = 0$ and $f''(2) > 0.$

This implies that

$$A > 0 ~\text{and that}~ B = (-4A).\tag1$$

At this point it is well to take a step back and realize that the constraint re the *location* (i.e value of $x$) that generates the minimum value of $f(x)$ is **absolutely independent** of $C$.  The only effect of the term $C$ is to *translate* the graph of the function $f(x) ~:~C$  units (either up or down).  Therefore, from an intuitive viewpoint, equation (1) above **exhausts** the info re $f$ has a minimum at $x=2$.

Therefore, there is no choice re continuing the problem.  Coefficient $B$ has been solved (re $B = -2A$) and you are **forced** to use the *other* premises (i.e. Given's) to *solve* for $A$ and $C$.  Once this is done, then $f$ will be **completely determined**, so the computation of $f(2)$ will **then** be straightforward.

---

$$A(5^2) + (-4A)(5) + C = 20 \implies 5A + C = 20.\tag2$$

$$A([-2]^2) + (-4A)(-2) + C = 41 \implies 12A + C = 41.\tag3$$

Subtracting equation (2) from equation (3) above, you have that

$$A = 3 \implies \{C = 5 ~\text{and}~ B = (-12)\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You don't need derivatives to solve this problem; it is known from high school that a quadratic polynomial $q(x)=ax^2+bx+1$ has an extremum at $\xi=-\frac b{2a}$, which is a minimum if $a>0$, a maximum if $a<0$, and that this extremum is equal to
$$q(\xi)=\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}=-\frac{\Delta(q)}{4a}.$$
To determine the coefficients of $q(x)$, you simply have to solve the system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}\begin{aligned}
q(-2)&=\phantom{2}4a-2b+c=41 \\
q(5)&= 25a+5b+c=20 \\
-\frac b{2a}&= 2
\end{aligned}\end{cases}
\implies
\begin{cases}\begin{aligned}
  21a+7b &=20 \\
b&= -4a
\end{aligned}\end{cases}
$$
Can you end the calculations?

*Added*: To answer the question of why the derivative is $0$ at a vertex $S(x_0,f(x_0))$ on the curve, suppose $S$ corresponds, say, to a local minimum. The intuitive explanation is that the slope of a chord $(SM)$ is negative is $M$ is *before* $M(x,f(x))$, i.e. since $x<x_0$ and $f(x)>f(x_0)$ the rate of variation is negative. Passing to the limit on left, we obtain that $f'(x_0)\le 0$.

On the other hand, if $M$ is  *after $s$, we have $x>x_0$ and still $f(x)>f(x_0)$, so the rate of variation is positive, and wwe can conclude <ith the same argument that $f'(x_0)\ge 0$.

Therefore we have both $f'(x_0)\le 0$ and  $f'(x_0)\ge 0$. Conclusion?

*Note*: This is only a necessary condition  to have a local extremum, certainly not a sufficient condition.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I did end the calculations and I got b = -4a using a derivative but now I realized I did not need it. My question was really that, if a function is minimized at x = 2, then a derivative at the point x = 2 (′(2) = 0) will equal zero because the line tangent to the function will be at the vertex and at the vertex the slope equals zero, I did not understand why the derivative equals zero and assumed that that was the case because at x = 2 the line is tangent to the vertex, sorry for the confusion, I put it really badly

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: @Scienceboy/ I don't have the time at the moment, but later, I'll add  an explanation if no one did it  before.

Comment: Please do! Haha, thank you again

Comment: @Scienceboy I posted a separate answer only because [1] your query contained the *derivatives* tag and [2] your query did **not** contain the *algebra-precalculus* tag.  Bernard's response represents an attempt to discuss your question(s) around relating the derivative to the slope of the tangent line.  My response represents the (extreme) view of refusing to engage in re-inventing the wheel, and therefore insisting on using the intermediate theorems from Calculus that at $(x=2), ~0 = f'(x) = (2Ax + B)$ and $~0 < f''(x) = 2A.$

Comment: @Scienceboy: I've added an explanation, as intuitive as I could. Hope it's clear.

Comment: That’s really helpful Bernard, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Just start with $f(x)=a(x-2)^2+c$.  From $f(-2)=41$ and $f(5)= 20$ you'll easily derive $a=3$ and $c=-7$.

Concerning the slope: According to Archimedes the slope of the straight line between the points $(x_1,f(x_1)$ and $(x_2,f(x_2))$ of a parabola equals the slope of the tangent at the mean of $x_1$ and $x_2$, that is $f'\bigl((x_1+x_2)/2\bigr)$.

Hence the slope at the vertex is zero due to the symmetry of the parabola.

Comment: I see, the question was really about the vertex, thank you for clarifying that.